# What to do if i need a Disposable item the whole run?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose

What if i need a Disposable item the entire run of my application?
There are some cases when this seems necessary, for example if i want to sync 2 threads with:
System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection.

If then one Thread uses Using, and disposes of it, and the other Thread hasn´t been able to shut down or is waiting on BlockingCollection (you can set a timeout), it will then get a Disposed Exception.

And there are probably more cases when this is true, so is there a way to bypass this, or should i simply make the object on Initialization, and dispose of it on Close?

EDIT: Here is what Visual Studio tells me when i use a Disposable item.

First how i use it, in an example:

```
private void Initialize()
        {
            Queue = new System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<byte[]>();
            Queue.Dispose();
        }
```

And i get this:

```
warning : CA2213 : Microsoft.Usage : 'Capture' contains field 'Capture.Queue' that is of IDisposable type: 'BlockingCollection<byte[]>'. Change the Dispose method on 'Capture' to call Dispose or Close on this field.
```

So that just get´s me confused. I have told it to dispose right after it has been made, and it still wants me to dispose of it:S

EDIT 2:

Is this the correct way of disposing object that are supposed to be alive the whole application run?

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
        Queue.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

As you can see, i added Queue there.

This doesn´t seem right though, feels weird to work with the Designer.cs file and add stuff under components.Dispose();

But hopefully it´s correct.

Comment: Don't use using on the object, and initialize it at program start, and dispose at program close. Is the problem that you can't guarantee someone else won't use `using` on the object?

Comment: The problem is just, should i do that? Visual Studio hates when i don´t dispose in Using, it says (You need to dispose disposable objects), even if i tell it to dispose the object on Close. So it just get´s me confused

Comment: Why do you dispose of it immediately in your `Initialize()` block? Was that simply to test the warning messages in VS?

Comment: @crush yes, to simply test it. I don´t use it there.

Comment: Do you use this `Initialize()` method simply to initialize all your class members? Why aren't you doing that in the constructor or in the class declaration `private BlockingCollection<byte[]> Queue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();`

Comment: @crush i always put everything there if i want them to be made on start. i thought they were supposed to be there;S

Comment: Oh, well i do also do that, thought it wasn´t a good idea though. But nice to hear it´s okay. And well, it still complains of the Dispose if that matters

Comment: There's nothing wrong with initializing a variable in it's field declaration. In fact, in many cases, I'd say it is preferred. The only time you wouldn't do this is if you are injecting a reference into the constructor, or you are going to initialize the field later in the program flow - which you should be careful with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36162/discussion-between-user2587718-and-crush)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Form project item template gets programmers into trouble.  They know that you're not supposed to edit the Designer.cs file.  But it is not quite that straight-forward.  Open the file and note the region:

```
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
```

*That's* the code you should not mess with.  And note that the Disposing(bool) override is **above** this region.  Which means that it is just fine to edit that one.

Best thing to do is to simply cut/paste the Dispose() method from the Designer.cs file into the form's source code file.  Now you have no trouble following the analyzer's advice:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) Queue.Dispose();
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the same answer as the others, but it explains a bit more:)

Comment: What are the advantages or disadvantages of doing that versus having the form subscribe to its own `FormClosed` or `Disposed` method?

Answer (score 1):

Just because an object is disposable, doesn't mean you have to dispose it!  Don't use a `using` block: this will dispose the object after it falls out of scope.  Just instantiate the object normally and dispose of it in your own good time (or never, if you expect to use it throughout the lifetime of the application).

Comment: Ah well that´s good to hear:)  Though, to create it at start, where should i do that, as there are many places, should i do it on, FormLoad, on Initialization, or at start in Private myDisposableobject object = new myDisposableobject(); ?

Comment: Where is the main reference to the disposable object kept?

Comment: The reference is at the top, as a Private Variable in the class.

Comment: You should always dispose the object in the same class that holds the primary reference to the object. Either in the destructor or in the class's `Dispose` method. Do any other classes hold reference to this same Queue instance?

Comment: That´s what i do. Or well, don´t know "destructor" but if you check my question, i think i added the "dispose" method.  And no, i haven´t used the reference anywhere.

Fun fact is though, if i use var Queue = new blabla, instead, it won´t complain if i dispose of it afterwards. But if i use the reference in the class, it complains.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is warning you that your object (a form called `Capture`) has a field that is disposable.  It is saying that when you dispose the form, you should also dispose the BlockingCollection.  It's right.  It has no way of knowing whether your application will continue after the form is disposed, so it's nagging you to clean up the form and its disposable fields when you're done with it.

Comment: But how to i "clean" it up?. I am disposing the object, and it still don´t "get it". Is there something wrong with how i do it?

Comment: Don't dispose the object right where it is instantiated (it will stop being useful almost immediately).  Instead, dispose the object in the form's `Dispose` method (add one if there isn't already one).

Comment: So i need to put it in the Designer.cs code? cause i guess that´s the Dispose method from what i can see.

Comment: I guess so.  Watch out for the designer re-writing that function on you!  It may be best to hoist the `Dispose` method into your own code, i.e. take it out of Capture.Designer.cs code and put it into Capture.cs instead.

Comment: I moved it. But it just doesn´t feel right, cause i can´t find anyone else who does this. And i still don´t understand way it doesn´t sense if i dispose of the object, will need to search more on this, it just feels fishy.

Comment: By declaring this disposable object (BlockingCollection) as a field of another disposable object (Form), you are making the Form the caretaker of the collection.  If the form gets shut down, closed, disposed, it makes sense to ensure that its owned objects also get properly disposed.  If this seems fishy to you, it's possible that in your application it isn't proper to make the form the owner of the collection, and that the collection should be managed outside the form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36161/discussion-between-csj-and-user2587718)